# How to do Visio-like diagramming with HTML5 + Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, diagram

I'm looking for options to draw Visio-like diagrams using HTML and Javascript.

Some examples of what I'm trying to accomplish:

- https://live.yworks.com/demos/view/vsdxexport/ (the `computer-network` example)
- [This Lucidchart example](https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/pages/chart/product-page/people-management-persona.png)

So far options I can think to explore are:

- Drag and Drop API with SVGs
- d3.js
- HTML5 Canvas

Is there any other tech or NPM packages that I should be aware of? It's not a free-form Visio clone, there's a fixed set of icons that I need to be able to "snap" together with lines. Lines can be straight or curved at 90 degrees like here:

[image: Diagramm]

And the icons can be dragged around in the canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [mxGraph](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/) library, licensed under Apache 2.0.

Distributed as an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mxgraph), on his [source code](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/tree/master/javascript/examples/grapheditor) you can find a fantastic example of an editor build upon it that you can also [try online](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html).

[image]